# Instantiate a Video Player?

Tags: word-choice, technical, science, software

I am writing a technical report where a number of video players are being loaded on a webpage.

Is it correct to say, "Instantiate a video player on the web page," or just, "Load a video player on the web page"

Thanks!

P.S.

I posed the question on writers.stackexchange and I received a response that  the the question was more appropriate on english.stackexchange

https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/18240/instantiate-a-video-player

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Have you not answered your own question? "I am writing a technical report where a number of video players are being **loaded** on a webpage." Why do you think *instantiate* is viable?

Comment: I guess I am wondering if the words "Load" and "Instantiate" can be used interchangeably in the context of video players.

Comment: *I am wondering if the words "Load" and "Instantiate" can be used interchangeably in the context of video players.* No.

Comment: @LouisMorin There is a technical distinction, but this site is oriented toward the general use of English, not jargon. You need an expert in the field, not an expert in the language.

Comment: We've had other questions here about words that have a precise technical meaning, I thought.  I don't think this is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

"Instantiate" means create (create an object-instance of a player-class).

"Load" might imply that you've started to stream media (e.g. video) to the player (technically you create the player, which then loads the video).

If you can't tell the difference then you should prefer an everyday non-technical word like "display" or "create", or just "are" or "put" or "place" ("there are several players on the web page", or "we placed several players on the web page").

Answer (score 0):

Having been a technical writer for several years, I would simply use "load." "Instantiate" is not an everyday word, and its first meaning is not a technical one. The first rule of technical writing is exactly like the first rule of writing in general: Keep it simple...

Comment: It depends on the audience.  I'm a technical writer and I use the word "instantiate" if I'm writing for, say, Java programmers, because it's technically correct.  But if I were writing end-user doc for non-programmers I probably wouldn't.